# How to know what r is doing behind the scene

Tags: r

As a new R user, I am very curious on what R is doing when we type in a function.  For example, I am using knn function in the class package.  All I need to do is type in knn and define by train and test data sets. Then what I get is the predicted class for my test data.  However, I am curious if there is a way to see the actual equations/formula that is in knn.  I have look through some knn references but am still curious on EXACTLY what R is doing! Is it possible to find such information?

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: simply type the name of the function, `knn` in this case, into the terminal with no parens or arguments. The function definition will be returned on the screen.

Comment: Type ?getAnywhere to see the help page for a very useful function.

Answer (score 11):

Well, the first thing you can do is simply type in the name of the function, which in many cases will give you the source right there.  For example:

```
> knn
function (train, test, cl, k = 1, l = 0, prob = FALSE, use.all = TRUE) 
{
    train <- as.matrix(train)
    if (is.null(dim(test))) 
        dim(test) <- c(1, length(test))
    test <- as.matrix(test)
    if (any(is.na(train)) || any(is.na(test)) || any(is.na(cl))) 
        stop("no missing values are allowed")
    p <- ncol(train)
    ntr <- nrow(train)
    if (length(cl) != ntr) 
        stop("'train' and 'class' have different lengths")
    if (ntr < k) {
        warning(gettextf("k = %d exceeds number %d of patterns", 
            k, ntr), domain = NA)
        k <- ntr
    }
    if (k < 1) 
        stop(gettextf("k = %d must be at least 1", k), domain = NA)
    nte <- nrow(test)
    if (ncol(test) != p) 
        stop("dims of 'test' and 'train' differ")
    clf <- as.factor(cl)
    nc <- max(unclass(clf))
    Z <- .C(VR_knn, as.integer(k), as.integer(l), as.integer(ntr), 
        as.integer(nte), as.integer(p), as.double(train), as.integer(unclass(clf)), 
        as.double(test), res = integer(nte), pr = double(nte), 
        integer(nc + 1), as.integer(nc), as.integer(FALSE), as.integer(use.all))
    res <- factor(Z$res, levels = seq_along(levels(clf)), labels = levels(clf))
    if (prob) 
        attr(res, "prob") <- Z$pr
    res
}
<bytecode: 0x393c650>
<environment: namespace:class>
>
```

In this case, you can see that the real work is being done by an external call to VR_knn.  If you want to dig deeper, you can go to http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/class/index.html, and download the source for this package.  If you download and extract the source, you will find a folder called "src" that holds the C code, and you can look through that, and find the source to that function:

```
void
VR_knn(Sint *kin, Sint *lin, Sint *pntr, Sint *pnte, Sint *p,
       double *train, Sint *class, double *test, Sint *res, double *pr,
       Sint *votes, Sint *nc, Sint *cv, Sint *use_all)
{
    int   i, index, j, k, k1, kinit = *kin, kn, l = *lin, mm, npat, ntie,
          ntr = *pntr, nte = *pnte, extras;
    int   pos[MAX_TIES], nclass[MAX_TIES];
    int   j1, j2, needed, t;
    double dist, tmp, nndist[MAX_TIES];

    RANDIN;
/*
    Use a 'fence' in the (k+1)st position to avoid special cases.
    Simple insertion sort will suffice since k will be small.
 */

    for (npat = 0; npat < nte; npat++) {
    kn = kinit;
    for (k = 0; k < kn; k++)
        nndist[k] = 0.99 * DOUBLE_XMAX;
    for (j = 0; j < ntr; j++) {
        if ((*cv > 0) && (j == npat))
        continue;
        dist = 0.0;
        for (k = 0; k < *p; k++) {
        tmp = test[npat + k * nte] - train[j + k * ntr];
        dist += tmp * tmp;
        }
/* Use 'fuzz' since distance computed could depend on order of coordinates */
        if (dist <= nndist[kinit - 1] * (1 + EPS))
        for (k = 0; k <= kn; k++)
            if (dist < nndist[k]) {
            for (k1 = kn; k1 > k; k1--) {
                nndist[k1] = nndist[k1 - 1];
                pos[k1] = pos[k1 - 1];
            }
            nndist[k] = dist;
            pos[k] = j;
/* Keep an extra distance if the largest current one ties with current kth */
            if (nndist[kn] <= nndist[kinit - 1])
                if (++kn == MAX_TIES - 1)
                error("too many ties in knn");
            break;
            }
        nndist[kn] = 0.99 * DOUBLE_XMAX;
    }

    for (j = 0; j <= *nc; j++)
        votes[j] = 0;
    if (*use_all) {
        for (j = 0; j < kinit; j++)
        votes[class[pos[j]]]++;
        extras = 0;
        for (j = kinit; j < kn; j++) {
        if (nndist[j] > nndist[kinit - 1] * (1 + EPS))
            break;
        extras++;
        votes[class[pos[j]]]++;
        }
    } else { /* break ties at random */
        extras = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < kinit; j++) {
        if (nndist[j] >= nndist[kinit - 1] * (1 - EPS))
            break;
        votes[class[pos[j]]]++;
        }
        j1 = j;
        if (j1 == kinit - 1) { /* no ties for largest */
        votes[class[pos[j1]]]++;
        } else {
/* Use reservoir sampling to choose amongst the tied distances */
        j1 = j;
        needed = kinit - j1;
        for (j = 0; j < needed; j++)
            nclass[j] = class[pos[j1 + j]];
        t = needed;
        for (j = j1 + needed; j < kn; j++) {
            if (nndist[j] > nndist[kinit - 1] * (1 + EPS))
            break;
            if (++t * UNIF < needed) {
            j2 = j1 + (int) (UNIF * needed);
            nclass[j2] = class[pos[j]];
            }
        }
        for (j = 0; j < needed; j++)
            votes[nclass[j]]++;
        }
    }

/* Use reservoir sampling to choose amongst the tied votes */
    ntie = 1;
    if (l > 0)
        mm = l - 1 + extras;
    else
        mm = 0;
    index = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= *nc; i++)
        if (votes[i] > mm) {
        ntie = 1;
        index = i;
        mm = votes[i];
        } else if (votes[i] == mm && votes[i] >= l) {
        if (++ntie * UNIF < 1.0)
            index = i;
        }
    res[npat] = index;
    pr[npat] = (double) mm / (kinit + extras);
    }
    RANDOUT;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your editor (e.g., RStudio) just type in the function name and execute the line. This shows you the source code of the function, i.e., type

```
knn
```

In RStudio you can also click on the function and hit F2. A new tab with the function source code will open.

Alternatively you could use

```
debug(knn)
knn(your function arguments)
```

and step through the function with the debugger.
When you are done use

```
undebug(knn)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Help Desk article in the [October 2006 R News](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2006-4.pdf) (a newsletter that has since evolved into [The R Journal](http://journal.r-project.org/)) shows how to access the source of R functions covering many of the different cases that you may need to use, from just typing the name of the function, to looking in namespaces, to finding the source files for compiled code.