# Trying to implement K-Nearest Neighbour in R, not sure where to go from here

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, nearest-neighbor

I'm trying to implement KNN algorithm in R.

This is the data set I'm working on (where first 2 columns are attributes and 3rd is the label):

```
2, 3, 1
4, 5, 1
6, 7, -1
8, 9, 1
5, 6, 1
7, 8, -1
```

My training set `train.X` is the first 4 attributes:

```
2, 3
4, 5
6, 7
8, 9
```

My test set `test.X` is the last 2 attributes:

```
5, 6
7, 8
```

`train.Y` represents the labels of the training set, and `test.Y` represents the labels of the test set (which I will soon try and predict to verify against this set).

The first step of the algorithm is to calculate the Euclidean distance between `test.X` and `train.X`, which I know how to calculate. However, I'm not sure about how to go about storing the distances so that I can then sort them in increasing order. How would I store them in a table for instance?

Appreciate any insight

Comment: Look at the `knn()` function from the `class` package. There's a good example in help file.

Comment: It doesn't show the implementation of knn, just how to use it.

Comment: you can get at the implementation of `knn()`with this code: `library(class); class:knn` details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19192407/how-to-know-what-r-is-doing-behind-the-scene

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this example](http://cbio.ensmp.fr/~jvert/svn/tutorials/practical/knnregression/knnregression.R) - it is pretty straighforward. Here are the essential points:

- **For each test point:**

  - Initialize a vector to store the distances to the train instances:

    `dsq <- numeric(nrow(train.X))`
  - store in `dsq` the distances to the training points
  - Sort `dsq` in increasing order:

    `ord <- order(dsq)`
  - Then, your output for the specific test point is

    `p.test <- mean(train.Y[ ord[1:k] ])`

where `k` is your chosen no of nearest neighbors.

Hope this helps...